How to use localStorage in next.js? I tried 3 methods, but they all did't work
here is my code, I want to write a context provider for toggle theme.
The CustomThemeProvider:
'use client'
import React, {createContext, useState} from "react";

type ThemeContextType = {
  theme: string;
  toggleTheme: () => void;
};

export const ThemeContext = createContext<ThemeContextType>({
  theme: 'light',
  toggleTheme: () => {}
});

export default function CustomThemeProvider({children}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  const initialTheme = window.localStorage.getItem('theme') === null ? 'light' : String(window.localStorage.getItem('theme'))
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(initialTheme);

  const toggleTheme = () => {
    const newTheme = theme === 'dark' ? 'light' : 'dark';
    window.localStorage.setItem('theme', newTheme);
    setTheme(newTheme);
  };

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme, toggleTheme }}>
      {children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
}

The LayoutContent:
'use client'
import React, {useContext} from "react";
import {ThemeContext} from "@/app/CustomThemeProvider";
import Footer from "@/app/components/Footer";
import Navigation from "@/app/components/Navigation";

export default function LayoutContent({
                         children,
                       }: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  const {theme, toggleTheme} = useContext(ThemeContext);

  return (
    <html lang="en" className={theme}>
    <body>
    <div id="layout" className="layout flex-col flex min-h-screen bg-skin-base">

      <Navigation themeToggleHandler={toggleTheme}/>

      <div className="flex-1">
        {children}
      </div>

      <div>
        <Footer/>
      </div>

    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
  );
}

I write the code like above, my webstorm tell me the error:

I try to modify it. The first try:

let initialTheme = 'light';
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    initialTheme = window.localStorage.getItem('theme') === null ? 'light' : String(window.localStorage.getItem('theme'))
}
const \[theme, setTheme\] = useState(initialTheme);

It did work, but another error showed:

The second try:
useEffect(), but it has the toggle latency.
Could you help me, Thanks!
No errors, and toggle theme fluently.

Just localStorage...

If you want to avoid the flash, you can use only CSS for the dark theme styling - I can see you are using tailwind, which has a handy dark: modifier. You can then add a script to the public directory and reference it directly with a <script> tag, as it will not be bundled with the rest of the app: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode#supporting-system-preference-and-manual-selection. This will not result in a flash as long as you place the tag above the actual page content, as it will be parsed first, before the rest of the document. Note that you will no longer need the provider, as all of the styles will be dependent on CSS. Whenever you want update the theme, you just change the class on the <html> tag and update the localStorage.
Alternatively, you can use a server component, and use cookies instead. You would pass the initial value as a prop to the provider, instead of getting it from localStorage. https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns#using-context-providers https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies
